# How to merge recordsets with different fields

Tags: sql, ms-access

In SQL, `union` can be used to append the rows of a recordset (table or query) to another one with the same fields. You can also append recordsets with different fields by combining the fields of both and assigning `null` values to fields for rows in a recordset that does not have those fields.

But what if each recordset has values that correspond to a key in the other one? Then combining fields with all `null` values for either recordset does not give the correct result.

I need to merge two recordsets with different fields in a single query. My recordsets are queries, but for the purposes of showing the problem, I'm representing them here as tables. Here is the setup in Access:

[image]

What I need is a datasheet with values for `Data_1` and `Data_2` when they exist, based on the values of ID1 and ID2:

| ID1 | ID2 | Data_1 | Data_2 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | A | X |
| 2 | 1 | B |  |
| 3 | 1 |  | Y |
| 4 | 1 | C | Z1 |
| 4 | 2 |  | Z2 |

I'm trying to do this by doing a `left join` from `ID1` to `ID1_1` and to `ID1_2`. This gives me the correct output for `ID1` values of 1, 2, and 3. But I have not been able to get the right output of the two rows for `ID1 = 4`.

For example, the SQL:

```
SELECT ID1, nz(ID2_1, ID2_2) AS ID2, Data_1, Data_2
FROM (ID1 LEFT JOIN Table_1 ON ID1.ID1 = Table_1.ID1_1) 
          LEFT JOIN Table_2 ON ID1.ID1 = Table_2.ID1_2
WHERE Data_1 Is Not Null OR Data_2 Is Not Null;
```

gives me two rows for `ID1 = 4`, but the second one is wrong:

[image]

and the SQL:

```
SELECT ID1, nz(ID2_1, ID2_2) AS ID2, Data_1, Data_2
FROM (ID1 LEFT JOIN Table_1 ON ID1.ID1 = Table_1.ID1_1) 
          LEFT JOIN Table_2 ON ID1.ID1 = Table_2.ID1_2
WHERE ID2_1 is not null and ID2_2 is null or
      ID2_1 is null and ID2_2 is not null or
      ID2_1 = ID2_2;
```

gives me only one row for `ID1 = 4`:

[image]

What am I doing wrong? What do I need to do to get the required output?

Comment: Your question is not necessarily specific to Access, but your syntax is. And any possible answers will be limited by the functional and syntactic limitations of the Access SQL engine. [Why should I “tag my RDBMS”?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/388759/why-should-i-tag-my-rdbms)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider:

```
SELECT Table_2.ID1_2, Table_2.ID2_2, Table_1.Data_1, Table_2.Data_2
FROM Table_2 LEFT JOIN Table_1 ON (Table_2.ID2_2 = Table_1.ID2_1) AND (Table_2.ID1_2 = Table_1.ID1_1)
UNION
SELECT Table_1.ID1_1, Table_1.ID2_1, Table_1.Data_1, Table_2.Data_2
FROM Table_1 LEFT JOIN Table_2 ON (Table_1.ID2_1 = Table_2.ID2_2) AND (Table_1.ID1_1 = Table_2.ID1_2);
```

=====================

Edit by questioner: This answer works perfectly, and it's one of those things that is obvious once you get it, but did not occur to me at all when I was trying to figure this out. So I want to explain how it works.

First, the table `ID1`, which I had `left join`'d to get all the rows of both `Table_n` tables included, is not needed.

Each of the two queries in the `union` does a `left join` from one `Table_n` to the other. This includes all the rows of the left-side table and inserts a new `Data_m` column, with corresponding values, where they exist, from that column of the other table. That creates a pair of tables that can be `union`'d, with duplicate rows excluded, to produce the desired output.

Comment: Simple, elegant, and obvious only after understanding it. Thank you.