# SQL: Can I avoid recalculating queries in a union?

Tags: sql, ms-access

This question arises from implementing the [answer to another question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69844438/how-to-merge-recordsets/#69847428). The code is of the form:

```
SELECT ...
FROM Query_1 LEFT JOIN Query_2 ON ...
UNION
SELECT ...
FROM Query_2 LEFT JOIN Query_1 ON ...;
```

The linked answer says they're tables, but as I stated in that question, I just called them tables for the purpose of showing the problem, and in what I'm doing, they're actually queries. So what I now have is two complicated queries that have to be calculated twice. And this computation is used multiple times in different contexts, with the `Query_n`s changing, so it doesn't work to save them as named queries.

Is there a way to tell Access to calculated each `Query_n` just once and refer to the results when the query is called the second time?

Comment: What let's you assume the (sub)queries would be executed twice?

Comment: No. Access may cache the queries, indeed if the records are few, but that's about it.

Comment: The `Query-n`s are each about a dozen lines of SQL. It's hard to believe that Access is smart enough to notice that this dozen lines of code over here is identical to that dozen lines of code over there and substitute the result of calculating the first occurrence for the second instead of calculating it again.

Comment: There's a good chance the optimizer notices that. The line count of the SQL isn't the right metric here. But well, Access certainly isn't the most sophisticated DBMS in the world. So maybe Access' optimizer isn't smart enough, yes. [Here](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=2ahUKEwi-q_aOp4H0AhUBNuwKHQttDm8QFnoECAcQAQ&url=https%3A%2F%2Fstackoverflow.com%2Fquestions%2F10100049%2Fmicrosoft-access-equivalent-of-explain-in-mysql&usg=AOvVaw3ZAzmyg5ACQ9dinnNOlhds) a question about how to get a plan in Access. You may want to try this and examine the plan.

Comment: @stickybit - The article linked there says that ShowPlan does not support subqueries.

Comment: I thought I've read before that there's a way to define a sort of temporary version of a saved query, so that you save the query only for as long as the code is running, and you can refer to that temp query repeatedly in the code. I thought the answer to my question might be how to do that.

Comment: I agree with sticky bit: the query optimizer will most likely do what you want automatically. If your query is slow, I suggest you should look in some other way for performance improvement. Just a shot in the dark: are you limiting the records that you bring from tables to the minimum neccessary in the first SELECT over tables?

Comment: No, I don't have a problem with the query running slowly. I'm just constantly on the lookout to make my code as efficient as possible. Having a block of code that is repeated with the same inputs is an obvious inefficiency, so I'd like to use the results of the first time instead of recalculating. It's great if the optimizer takes care of that for me, but I'd be happier if I could implement the optimization directly in my code.